# CSV row headers are not coming in Athena query from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I exported my SQL DB into CSV and imported those CSV files into S3. I Created Crawlers which are working fine. Now my CSV files have header row with Column Names. Those are not populating when I am sending query in Athena, The header row is also coming as datarow and columns are named as col0, col1 etc.

Please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your file format, you should be able to **skip the header row** by using this parameter in the table DDL:

```sql
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'skip.header.line.count'='1',
  ...
)
```

Comment: I do not want to skip the header row. I want to use table headers as column name. As you advised, I found that in Athena and can see the DDL but can not modify. On the other hand if I try to open that in Glue from Athena console (by clicking 3 dots), surprisingly it is showing 5 columns in Glue, whereas in the query console it is showing 3 columns.

Comment: Actually my table column names are showing as the first row of the table in Athena query. Column names are coming as col0, col1, col2 etc. How to use the first row of the csv file as column header in Athena query result?

Comment: @pray How did you create the table? If you created it with an AWS Glue crawler, it should detect the header row and use it to name the columns. You can always rename the columns in the AWS Glue Catalog -- go to the Glue console, select the table and edit the column names. Then, the above code will tell Athena to skip the first row when reading the files.

Comment: 1. I clicked "View in Glue" in Athena table name (3 dots at right).  Then selected "Edit Schema" in Glue. Saved that. Execute the Crawler once again. But the old problem still raised.

2. Where to write the following, please explain little more:

TBLPROPERTIES (
  'skip.header.line.count'='1',
  ...
)

Comment: If you click the 3 dots, you can select "Generate table DDL". This will show the SQL statement that was used to create the table. If I want to modify it, I normally DROP the table, then run the DDL again, but with the modified statement (eg changing location or a table property). If you feel more comfortable with AWS Glue, you could try using a Crawler to create another table (with a different name) to see if it gets it right this time.

Comment: As advised, I clicked  3 dots, and selected "Generate table DDL". I changed the column name and types in DDL by create table. I added "'skip.header.line.count'='1'," and from the table now the first row is removed and column names are coming successfully. I created this new table in a different name and upto this it is fine.

But when the crawler runs in schedule, again the old table table with old format is generating ignoring my newly created table. I am not finding where to map the newly created table in the crawler :-(.

Please help

Comment: Oh, I am really dumb in this aws. Let me tell you in little detail:

1. I have SQL DB
2. I am exporting that in CSV files for each table
3. Then I am uploading those CSV files into S3 bucket in a schedule to get updated SQL data
4. Then I am using Glue to fetch the records into different S3, say bucket 2
5. My next job is to Connect these files (SQL DB tables) from Bucket 2 with QuickSight

I thought I need to run Crawler periodically, to get updated CSV files from Source S3 to Target S3 bucket so that my QuickSight dashboard will be updated automatically.

Comment: I have only used AWS Glue crawlers for creating table definitions in the Data Catalog for use with Amazon Athena. Once the table is created, I don't use the crawler any more.

Comment: I see. But for my case, I need the updated data frequently into S3 bucket. Is there any way to get that without crawler? May be I am following wrong method, which I am not sure.

What you suggested is working nicely, for one time. But once the crawler is running, the table structure is getting messed up again :-(

Comment: When a query is run in Amazon Athena, it uses all files found in the 'location', including subdirectories. Any files existing at the time that the query is run will be scanned for data. The crawler does not need to run unless new partition directories have been created. If your dashboard is using Amazon Athena for queries, then the crawler does not need to run after the table is created.

Comment: What a relief :-). I am so dumb, I did not know this earlier. Thanks a lot for your guidance. Henceforth, I will create crawler only to bring the data. The will edit the DDL as you suggested. Then will use Athena query to pull the data and show to QuickSight.